# MaxElements of column

Tags: java, matrix

My question is how to find three largest elements in column of matrix. If there was about finding only largest element i would know, but here i have no idea. Here is my code for the largest element in column:

```
public static void Column(int m, int[][] arr) 
{ 

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) { 

        int max = arr[0][i]; 
        for (int j = 1; j < arr[i].length; j++) 
            if (arr[j][i] > max) 
                max = arr[j][i]; 

        System.out.println(max); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the `i` and `j` in the following pieces:

```
 int max = arr[0][i];

 if (arr[j][i] > max) 
            max = arr[j][i];
```

Also in the `j` loop the first value should be zero. if you wish to keep it at `1` then you should use `<=` as the conditional.